# Open link in a div

Tags: html

In a `<a>` label I know I can do `target="nameframe"` and show the content of the link in the target frame. Can I do the same with divs?

I tried to put a name of a div and after, write it in target, but it doesn't work, it works like the target was a `_blank`.

Comment: no you cannot, as far as i know. can I ask why?

Comment: I don't think it is meant to work with divs

Answer (score 1):

No. You can only target frames, that is the purpose of frames. Note that iframes are inline elements that appear in a regular page instead of a frameset and may be suitable for your needs.

You could fake it by fetching the content with JavaScript (i.e. Ajax) and using DOM manipulation to put the results in the div. It wouldn't be an independent page though, so your stylesheets and scripts would bleed through.

Answer (score 1):

I dont think its possible to do that, but you can insert an `<iframe>` into a `<div>`